# How to use the ContT monad transformer?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, continuations

The `ContT` monad transformer has the same implementation like the `Cont` monad, but I'm not able to apply it to all three `Either` cases

- `Right`
- `Left` from the current monadic action
- `Left` from a previous monadic computation

The last one fails and all attempts to fix it failed as well:

```js
const record = (type, o) => (
  o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type.name || type,
  o);

const union = type => (tag, o) => (
  o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type,
  o.tag = tag.name || tag,
  o);

const match = (tx, o) => o[tx.tag] (tx);

const Either = union("Either");
const Left = left => Either(Left, {left});
const Right = right => Either(Right, {right});

const eithChain = mx => fm =>
  match(mx, {
    Left: _ => mx,
    Right: ({right: x}) => fm(x)
  });

const ContT = contt => record(ContT, {contt});

const contChainT = mmk => fmm =>
  ContT(c => mmk.contt(x => fmm(x).contt(c)));

const main = foo =>
  contChainT(ContT(k => k(foo))) (mx =>
    eithChain(mx) (x =>
      x === 0
        ? ContT(k => k(Left("ouch!")))
        : ContT(k => k(Right(x * x)))));

main(Right(5)).contt(console.log); // Right(25)
main(Right(0)).contt(console.log); // Left("ouch!")
main(Left("yikes!")).contt(console.log); // Type Error
```

This is fruststrating. Any hints are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` function does not type check.

```js
const main = foo =>
  contChainT(ContT(k => k(foo))) (mx =>
    eithChain(mx) (x =>
      x === 0
        ? ContT(k => k(Left("ouch!")))
        : ContT(k => k(Right(x * x)))));
```

First, let's simplify it. Given, `const pureContT = x => ContT(k => k(x))` we can rewrite `main` as follows.

```js
const main = foo =>
  contChainT(pureContT(foo)) (mx =>
    eithChain(mx) (x =>
      pureContT(x === 0
        ? Left("ouch!")
        : Right(x * x))));
```

However, `chain(pure(x))(f)` is the same as `f(x)` (left identity law). Hence, we can further simplify.

```js
const main = mx =>
  eithChain(mx) (x =>
    pureContT(x === 0
      ? Left("ouch!")
      : Right(x * x)));
```

Here, you can see the problem. The `eithChain` function has the following type.

```hs
Either e a -> (a -> Either e b) -> Either e b
```

However, the callback given to `eithChain` returns a `ContT` instead of an `Either`.

---

I would actually say that you're approaching this problem wrong.

```hs
ContT r m a = (a -> m r) -> m r

-- Therefore

ContT r (Either e) a = (a -> Either e r) -> Either e r
```

This is not what you want. You should be using the `EitherT` transformer instead.

```hs
EitherT e m a = m (Either e a)

Cont r a = (a -> r) -> r

-- Therefore

EitherT e (Cont r) a = Cont r (Either e a) = (Either e a -> r) -> r
```

Here's what I would do.

```js
// Left : e -> Either e a
const Left = error => ({ constructor: Left, error });

// Right : a -> Either e a
const Right = value => ({ constructor: Right, value });

// Cont : ((a -> r) -> r) -> Cont r a
const Cont = runCont => ({ constructor: Cont, runCont });

// either : (e -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Either e a -> b
const either = left => right => either => {
    switch (either.constructor) {
    case Left: return left(either.error);
    case Right: return right(either.value);
    }
};

// MonadEitherT : Monad m -> Monad (EitherT e m)
const MonadEitherT = ({ pure, bind }) => ({
    pure: x => pure(Right(x)),
    bind: m => f => bind(m)(either(e => pure(Left(e)))(f))
});

// MonadCont : Monad (Cont r)
const MonadCont = {
    pure: x => Cont(k => k(x)),
    bind: m => f => Cont(k => m.runCont(x => f(x).runCont(k)))
};

// MonadEitherCont : Monad (EitherT e (Cont r))
const MonadEitherCont = MonadEitherT(MonadCont);

// main : Either String Number -> EitherT String (Cont r) Number
const main = either => MonadEitherCont.bind(MonadCont.pure(either))(x =>
    MonadCont.pure(x === 0 ? Left("ouch!") : Right(x * x)));

// show : Either e a -> String
const show = either
    (e => `Left(${JSON.stringify(e)})`)
    (x => `Right(${JSON.stringify(x)})`);

// print : Either e a -> ()
const print = x => console.log(show(x));

main(Right(5)).runCont(print); // Right(25)
main(Right(0)).runCont(print); // Left("ouch!")
main(Left("yikes!")).runCont(print); // Left("yikes!")
```

Comment: But why would I use `ContT` then? When I look at the Kleisli arrow `a -> Cont r m b` ~ `a -> (b -> m r) -> m r` ~ `(b -> m r) -> (a -> m r)` it is a transformation of the domain. Do you have any comprehensible example?

Comment: @scriptum The most common use case for the `ContT` monad would be to flatten nested  monadic computations. The following [blog post](https://ro-che.info/articles/2019-06-07-why-use-contt) by Roman Cheplyaka might interest you.

Comment: @AaditMShah I implemented a version based on `ContT` and posted it as a complementary answer.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing to Aadit's answer I managed to implement a version with `ContT` as transformer. All I needed to manipulate the current continuation was the standard Monad `Cont` implementation and the corresponding `lift`:

```js
const record = (type, o) => (
  o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type.name || type,
  o);

const union = type => (tag, o) => (
  o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type,
  o.tag = tag.name || tag,
  o);

const match = (tx, o) => o[tx.tag] (tx);

const Either = union("Either");
const Left = left => Either(Left, {left});
const Right = right => Either(Right, {right});

const eithChain = mx => fm =>
  match(mx, {
    Left: _ => mx,
    Right: ({right: x}) => fm(x)
  });

const ContT = contt => record(ContT, {contt});

const contChainT = mmk => fmm =>
  ContT(k => mmk.contt(x => fmm(x).contt(k)));

const contLiftT = chain => mmk =>
  ContT(k => chain(mmk) (k));

const log = x => (console.log(x), x);

const main = foo =>
  contChainT(contLiftT(eithChain) (foo)) (x =>
    x === 0
      ? ContT(k => Left("yikes!"))
      : ContT(k => k(x * x)));

const foo = main(Right(5)).contt(x => Right(log(x))); // logs 25
const bar = main(Right(0)).contt(x => Right(log(x)));
const baz = main(Left("ouch!")).contt(x => Right(log(x)));

log(foo); // Right(25)
log(bar); // Left("yikes!")
log(baz); // Left("ouch!")
```

It seems as if `ContT`/`M` with an arbitrary base monad `M` and `T`/`Cont` with an arbitrary transformer `T` are commutative in their effetcs. I don't have the mathematical skills to prove such claim though.